# BAM Continuation issue with TPE

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-bam

I have 2 Orchestrations in a parent/child relationship in my solution. The parent calls the child directly. The child Orchestration calls out to WCF services and the responses are returned to the child orchestration then back to the parent.

I have used the TPE to create a tracking profile using Continuation between the parent and child orchs. This works well as long as no errors occur, but when testing error scenarios in the services, rows get left in the Active table as the continuation never ends correctly.

If I was using the BAM API I would be able to specifically end the continuation in the child orchestration's error handler, but there does not seem to be any way of doing this from the TPE.

Could anyone please advise if this error handling scenario is possible through the TPE?

Comment: Do you mean that the orch do not get a response from the Wcf service some times?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem using a terminate shape in an orchestration where continuation was used. For other people looking for an answer, we could only solve it with help from the BAM API.

`Microsoft.BizTalk.Bam.EventObservation.OrchestrationEventStream.EndActivity("act_Name", "interchangeId");`

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the first shape in the orchestrations error handler as the milestone to use in TPE. This works like a charm!